# I'm just messing around with higher order Function in kotlin. I am passing these two string arguments

Tags: java, string, kotlin, lambda, arguments

I am passing these two string parameters into the lambda exp. And I am getting weird error separate it using (;) and when I did this it only print just one val(name2) or "Me" and i want to print both strings
Here's the code:

```
fun callMeAgain(str1 : String, str2: String, myFun: (String, String) -> String) {

    val callMyNameOverHere = myFun(str1, str2)
    print(callMyNameOverHere)
}

fun main() {
    val name = "I"
    val name2 = "Me"

    val mylambda : (String, String) -> String = { name: String, name2: String -> name; name2 }
}
```

Comment: What is the `mylambda` *supposed* to do? It takes two parameters and then what? Your type does not match the actual statement you then wrote in the lambda body: what is `name; name2` or `name, name2` supposed to do?

Comment: it has to print (I Me)and it is (name; name2) actually without error. but if i write (name, name2) it shows an error that use (;) separate the expression in same line.. i just wanna print these two strings using lambda

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want `myLambda` to return the concatenation between the two `String`s passed in input:

```
val mylambda: (String, String) -> String = { a: String, b: String -> a + b }
```

This way you are creating a lambda function and you are assigning this function to `val mylambda`.
Then, if you want to pass `name` and `name2` to `mylambda` and get the result, you have to do:

```
val result = mylambda(name, name2)
```

You can then print the result if that's what you want:

```
print(result)
```

Comment: Thanks that first concatenation statement worked for me.